# Android orientation change with fragments handled by fragment activity

Tags: android, eclipse, android-fragments

I have a fragment activity which loads a full row for a single record selected, that's working fine the first time, but if I change the orientation it crashes and throws "Source not found". When I debug line by line, some TextView are not available (return null), this is my fragment Activity Code:

```
@Override


public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)` 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
        setContentView(R.layout.client_layout);

        if (savedInstanceState==null)
        {
            clientActivityViewModel= (ClientActivityViewModel)getLastCustomNonConfigurationInstance();

            if(clientActivityViewModel==null)
            {
                clientActivityViewModel= new ClientActivityViewModel(getBaseContext());
                if (bundle== null)
                {
                    bundle= getIntent().getExtras();
                }
                clientActivityViewModel.setAccountId(bundle.getString("accountId"));
                clientActivityViewModel.GetAccountInformation(bundle.getString("accountId"));
                clientInformationActivity= new ClientInformationActivity();
                clientInformationActivity.setAccountInformation(clientActivityViewModel.getAccountInformation());

                clientActivityViewModel.GetAccountComplementaryInformation(bundle.getString("accountId"));
                clientComplementaryInformationActivity= new ClientComplementaryInformationActivity();
                clientComplementaryInformationActivity.setAccountComplementaryInformation(clientActivityViewModel.getAccountComplementaryInformation());
            }

            if(clientActivityViewModel!=null)
            {
                clientActivityViewModel.GetAccountInformation(clientActivityViewModel.getAccountId());
                clientInformationActivity= new ClientInformationActivity();
                clientInformationActivity.setAccountInformation(clientActivityViewModel.getAccountInformation());

                clientActivityViewModel.GetAccountComplementaryInformation(clientActivityViewModel.getAccountId());
                clientComplementaryInformationActivity= new ClientComplementaryInformationActivity();
                clientComplementaryInformationActivity.setAccountComplementaryInformation(clientActivityViewModel.getAccountComplementaryInformation());

                if (clientActivityViewModel != null) 
                { 
                    pager = (ViewPager) findViewById (R.id.pager);
                    MyFragmentPagerAdapter adapter = new MyFragmentPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
                    adapter.addFragment(clientInformationActivity);
                    adapter.addFragment(clientComplementaryInformationActivity);
                    adapter.addFragment(new ClientAddressActivity());
                    adapter.addFragment(new ClientPaymentInfoActivity());
                    adapter.addFragment(new ClientDescriptionInfoActivity());
                    pager.setAdapter(adapter);
                } 
            }
        }
    }


    @Override
    public Object onRetainCustomNonConfigurationInstance()
    { 
        if (clientActivityViewModel== null)
        {
            clientActivityViewModel= new ClientActivityViewModel(getBaseContext());
            bundle= getIntent().getExtras();
            clientActivityViewModel.setAccountId(bundle.getString("accountId"));
        }
        return clientActivityViewModel;
    }
```

Comment: I don't see any textviews in the code posted...

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you are saying that when orientation changes your code does not run.

If this is the case, then when orientation changes again **Oncreate** is called.  That is why your activity is not running correctly after the first time.

To fix this you have declare this in your Manifest file:

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" 
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|screensize"
```

The last line is only availabe in android 3.0 and above

Comment: Should be `screenSize`.(otherwise it won't compile)